# AWS. Storing and displaying the profile picture of users

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a requirement of storing andd displaying the profile picture of my users. So I used the S3.upload function in my nodeJs backend to store the image. 
And after the image is stored I stored the link in database  to fetch it using **ng-source** in my view. It worked but the link got **expired** after few hours and did not work. Below is the code for my upload. **Is there any solution in how to do this** or **any other better way to do this**.

```
   var body = fs.createReadStream(file.file.path);

      //Upload the photo to AWS

      s3.upload({Body: body}, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        if (data) {

        //getSignedUrl and Store it in Database
          var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
          var url =  req.params.doctorId +  "/Images/"  + fileName;
          var s3 = new AWS.S3()
              ,params = {Bucket: S3Bucket, Key:url };
          s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
            if (err || url == null) res.status(500).send({msg: "amazon s3 error"});
            else if (url) {
              if(req.body.picture == 1) {
                User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.doctorId, {$set: {'FileName.profilePicture': url}},
                    function (err, doc) {
                      if (err)
                        res.sendStatus(500);
                      else
                        res.send({url: url});
                    });
```

Comment: Don't store the url but the params needed to generate it and do it every time you want to show it

Comment: @AmiramKorach wont that take more time to load and also do I need to resize the images before uploading.

Comment: I don't know about that. You can check how much time it takes. Anyway, the fact that this url is expired tells you not to save it. About the size, if you want to store a big image and fetch it with small size on demand you can use a service like cloudinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're getting the URL from a signed URL and signed URLs expire by design.

From [Share an Object with Others](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) on AWS docs:

> All objects by default are private. Only the object owner has permission to access these objects. However, the object owner can optionally share objects with others by creating a pre-signed URL, using their own security credentials, to grant time-limited permission to download the objects.

It seems like you're not exactly storing "secret" resources here that access has to be granted to, then the best approach here is store the image publicly. This is trivial to do and you simply have to set the `ACL` to `public-read` when you call `PutObject` or `upload`. That way you'll know the URL for the object without actually having to retrieve it:

```
https://s3-[region].amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[file]
```

This is what your upload statement would look like then:

```
s3.upload({ Body: body, ACL: 'public-read' }, function (err, data) {
```